# Choosing number of samples to train a model

Tags: naive-bayes, validation, accuracy, regression-strategies, train

(On behalf of a colleague)

I have performed some modelling based on a naïve Bayes classifiers model (weighted genomic risk score) and obtained reasonable ROCAUC results (used ROCR, pROC, and SDMtools in R) .

[image: table]

Currently the model performs well when applied to a test set that is constructed of half cases and half controls. For example this current model with effect size of almost 2, seems to predict cases and controls with 80% accuracy. This is not the normal rate of incidence in the general population. The training set is similar to the test set in that it comprises around 260 cases and controls (in almost equal proportions). But chances are if I take the same model and test it using a normal population, then it may not have the same predictability. I know that this is most likely due to the fact that the current training set is only around 260 and the test set at 100. I need to find out how many cases and controls I need to train on in order to be at least 80% sure that the model chosen, will perform just as well in a normal population.

If I want to be, say 90% confident, that the same model will work in a random population representative cohort how many samples do I need to have trained the model on?

Comment: In order to obtain an answer you would need to stipulate a quantitative criterion for what it means to "work".  Could you expand your post to provide that information?

Comment: @whuber

Edited, let me know if the question still isn't clear.

Comment: What matters here is whether the distributions of properties is the same in your sample as the population. Ie, is your sample a random sample? There isn't going to be a simple number of samples that you will need (like 5 more) that we can just tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have improperly cast the problem IMHO.  The fundamental goal is to estimate risk accurately, with a well-calibrated model and with good predictive discrimination.  If a sample is not representative of the population but the model contains the covariates that describe how the sample is different, the model has no problem transporting to the population.  Any other approach is not based on sound statistical principles and results in a lot of ad hoc recipes.

Once you are set on a goal of accurate risk estimation, use proper accuracy scoring rules and drop sens, spec, PPV, NPV, or classification accuracy.

There is a nice literature on when logistic models work when oversampling has taken place.  The worst thing that can usually happen is that the intercept is distorted, but the slopes are usually OK.